# Creating a simple VS2008 visualizer inside autoexp.dat (problem with casting)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, casting, visualizer

I have a large project of mixed C/C++. I've created a simple visualizer for the ICU UnicodeString class as follows...

```
[inside autoexp.dat]
icu_4_2::UnicodeString {
        preview     ([$c.fUnion.fFields.fArray,su])
}
```

...and that works fine. Inside the debugger wherever I see the object I now see the text inside in the preview line.

I then created a wrapper class containing one of these objects as follows...

```
class StringHandleData
{
public:
    icu_4_2::UnicodeString str;
};
```

...and then created another visualizer for this...

```
[inside autoexp.dat]
StringHandleData {
    preview     ([$c.str.fUnion.fFields.fArray,su])
}
```

...which again, works fine. Whenever I see a StringHandleData object in the debugger I see the text inside in the string.

However, my problem comes when I define a typedef I can use inside C code like this...

```
typedef void* StringHandle;
```

...which under the hood is actually just a ptr to a StringHandleData object. So when I try and create a visualizer for the StringHandle type like this...

```
[inside autoexp.dat]
StringHandle {
    preview     ([((StringHandleData)$c).str.fUnion.fFields.fArray,su])
}
```

...it doesn't work. I've tried lots of other ways of casting the object too but with no luck so far. If I go to my watch window and cast a StringHandle like this... **(StringHandleData*)stringHandle** then the debugger makes the cast and previews correctly - but I just can't seem to get it to do it automatically from inside autoexp.dat

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have to tell the debugger to dereference the pointer.  Something like `*(StringHandleData*)`.

Comment: I think I've tried almost every combinations of *, &, . and -> with no success. Feels like how I use to deal with compiler errors 20 years ago when I first started learning C.

Answer (score 3):

Visual studio's visualiser is blind to typedefs and will think `StringHandle` is a `void *`.