# visualizer for simple typedef type in autoexp.dat (to display fourcc DWORD as chars)

Tags: visual-studio, typedef, visualizer, fourcc

We are using a lot of fourCC custom types in our code, like:

```
typedef unsigned int fourcc;
fourcc flag;
if (flag=='add') ...;
else if (flag=='del') ...;
etc...
```

We would like to be able to add a visualizer in autoexp.dat to display these as four chars.

Unfortunately, it seems that autoexp.dat's visualizer ignore the typedef, and don't want to touch basic types (as is confirmed here [Creating a simple VS2008 visualizer inside autoexp.dat (problem with casting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584228/creating-a-simple-vs2008-visualizer-inside-autoexp-dat-problem-with-casting) )

Is there any know workaround, that doesn't have any impact on the performance of the code, to be able to see those fourcc in the debuger as chars?